# How to mount internal disk that is not visible in terminal

Tags: terminal, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, ssd

I have somehow deleted/unmounted an internal disk drive from my macbook while wanted to freshly install macOS. I had bootcamp with windows before and then I deleted that partition.

I boot from USB key with macOS install file to get to terminal. When I list the drives I get following (the same happened when I tried with internet recovery):

```
/dev/disk0 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      FDisk_partition_scheme                       *15.7 GB    disk0
   1:                   Apple_HFS Install macOS Big Sur  15.7 GB    disk0s1

/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.8 GB     disk1
   1:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         1.8 GB     disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.8 GB     disk2
                                 Physical Store disk1s1
   1:                APFS Volume macOS Base system       1.6 GB     disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 77.8 MB    disk2s2
```

The internal drive is missing. Also in disk utility there is no internal storage disk. This disk should have size of 1TB.

If I do not use USB key with macOS install file or internet recovery there is just black screen.

Mac model is: MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016) model A1707

Image from GUI Disk utility:
[image: disk utility screenshot]

Is there something that I could do to mount the disk drive?

Comment: Can you add to your question  the exact model of Mac and the terminal results of command `diskutil list internal` ?

Comment: Also, a picture of how the drive looks in Disk Utility (the GUI application) might help.

Comment: Mac model is: MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016) model A1707

Comment: Perfect, and the results of `diskutil list internal` command from recovery mode?

Comment: It is empty. 
`-bash-3.2# diskutil list internal`
`-bash-3.2#`

Comment: I'm afraid the SSD is broken. And on this model, you cannot replace it because it is soldered to the motherboard. You can contact Apple if they have a solution, else you can use an external ssd in a thunderbolt 3 enclosure. You can try doing a Reset SMC and Reset NVRAM but I have a doubt about the effectiveness. Good luck.

Comment: I have tried to reset SMC and NVRAM and yes nothing. This happened when I removed bootcamp windows partition. Any other idea? :)

Comment: I think it's chance. The ssd must have a toothache ;-}  You can try stopping the Mac and retry after one or two hours, but I'm skeptical

Comment: Yeah. I am trying to see a miracle for one week now.